# DotDotDot collapse HTML code

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using dotdotdot to collapse plain text. But in this case I have to desplegate an email on my page and want that this is displayed with a "view more" button.
The thing is that it comes with raw html and I don't know if the plugin support this.

The html I have is this:

```
<div dir="ltr">
ASDF<br>
    <div class="gmail_quote">
        ---------- Mensaje reenviado ----------<br>
        De: <b class="gmail_sendername">BLABLA</b> <span dir="ltr">&lt;<a href="mailto:BLA@BLA.com">dBLA@BLA.com</a>&gt;</span><br>
        Fecha: 30 de octubre de 2014, 9:58<br>
        Asunto: SUBJECT<br>
        Para: AAAA &lt;<a href="mailto:aaa@a.com">A@A.com</a>&gt;<br>
        Cc: BBBBB &lt;<a href="mailto:bbb@b.com">B@B.com</a>&gt;<br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div dir="ltr">
            <div style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: small">DDDDDDDDD<br>
                <br>
            </div>
            <div style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: small">ASDFASDFA<br>
                &nbsp;<img src="https://kimberlytries.files.wordpress.com/2014/07/giphy.gif" height="247" width="500"><br>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>          
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: How many lines of text are you going to need? Because you can truncate one line of text with CSS without need for any JS

Comment: A lot, because as it is an email it could contain a full conversation in it. CSS should work if it was plain text, but does it work with html code? Thanks!